# Does "It would be the last time..." refer to the past or the present?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases, expressions

From my understanding, in direct speech/conversation (not as a narrative), "That would be the last time..." refer to the past event, and "This would be the last time..." refers to a current or recent event. Is that correct?

For examples:

> "That would be the last time I saw him."

> "This would be the last time she would see him."

But what does "It would be the last time..." refer to?

For example:

> "It would be the last time they would ever see each other."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See: [future in the past](https://www.thoughtco.com/future-in-the-past-grammar-1690811)

Comment: @TinfoilHat

I intended it as a direct speech in conversation and not as a narrative, so I think the Future-in-the-Past tense form doesn't apply here?

Comment: 'It' requires an antecedent, which will disambiguate.

Comment: The form "it would be the last time" is not generally used outside of narrative. It's used after describing some other action, practically always in the past.

Answer (score -1):

It pretty much has to refer to the past from the point of view of the narrator who is articulating the sentence, because it presupposes a knowledge of what will happen at some point after the "it" of "it would be the last time".

Comment: Hello, Can you tell me if my assumption that ["That would be the last time..." refer to the past event and "This would be the last time..." refer to the present occurrence or something that just recently happened] is correct? What do you think?

Comment: The narrator is speaking in the present from the point of view of someone in the past who knows what will happen in the future from that viewpoint. Whether it’s “that” or “this” doesn’t matter.

Comment: @Xanne
What I mean here is not about someone who say it while narrating/telling a story, but say it during a conversation with (talking to) another person. For example, in a scenario like this: A band was performing their last concert before disbanding. In the middle of the performance, the leader said to the band members; "This would be the last time we performed together." (I think if he uses the word 'that' instead of 'this' here, it doesn't make sense content-wise.)

Comment: @Xanne
And after the concert ended, at the afterparty while they were watching the recording of the show together, The Leader said to the band members; "That would be the last time we performed together."
So is what the band leader said correct in the word choise and usage?

Comment: @Dearyme That statement doesn't make sense to me. If he's talking in the present tense he should say "This **will** be the last time ..." or "This **is** the last time..."

Comment: I already got the answer from Bing AI. I guess I'll have to trust him. 
[Bing AI: Yes, that is correct. In direct speech or conversation, “That would be the last time…” refers to a past event that has already happened, while “This would be the last time…” refers to a current or recent event that is still relevant or ongoing. For example:
“That would be the last time I ever saw him.” (The speaker is talking about a past event that is over and done with.)
“This would be the last time I ever trust you.” (The speaker is talking about a current or recent event that is still affecting them.)]

Comment: [Bing AI: “It would be the last time…” can refer to either a past or a current event, depending on the context and the tense of the verb. It can also indicate a hypothetical or conditional situation, where something might or might not happen. For example: “It would be the last time I ever spoke to her.” (The speaker is talking about a past event that has already happened.) “It would be the last time I ever drink this coffee.” (The speaker is talking about a current or recent event that is still relevant or ongoing.)]

Comment: Continuation from above: [“It would be the last time I ever go there if I knew what was waiting for me.” (The speaker is talking about a hypothetical or conditional situation that might or might not happen.)]

Comment: [Bing AI: In this sentence, “It would be the last time they would ever see each other.” I think it refers to the past, because the verb ‘see’ is also in the past tense (‘would see’). This suggests that the speaker is talking about a past event that has already happened. If the speaker wanted to refer to the present, they would use the present tense (‘will see’).

Comment: Continuation from above: [For example: “It would be the last time they would ever see each other.” (The speaker is talking about a past event that has already happened.) “It would be the last time they will ever see each other.” (The speaker is talking about a current or recent event that is still relevant or ongoing.)]

Comment: @Dearyme BingAI is not a reliable source of information.

Comment: @Barmar
Why does everyone seem to interpretent the word 'would' here as the past tense of 'will'? I'm referring it to the present tense usage, just as the words 'could' or 'might' can also be used in present tense. In my opinion, if he says "This will be the last time we perform together...", it's more appropriate to say before they start the concert. And if he says "This is the last time...", it's just stating a fact. But the word 'would' here would be stating both a fact and a possibility. It will carries a deeper meaning and shows the speaker's feelings, such as sadness or melancholy.

Comment: @ohwilleke
I've asked Bing AI so many questions, and he can give very detailed explanations down to the very small things. He can explain the meaning of a sentence, the parts of a sentence, the relationship between sentences in a conversation, what the speaker was thinking or feeling while saying it, what the difference would be if any part of the sentence was changed, etc. And all his explanations make sense to me. Clearly he's the real deal. So I will be using Bing AI from now on. Thanks for your response to me.

Comment: All those uses of "this would" sound like narrative description to my American ears. Is this use for present tense speech a British thing?